# Flipping a circular UIView

Tags: ios, uikit

I'm working on a project that has circular views that flip over.

So far, I've tried a couple of the solutions provided here on SOflow:

- simply rounding the corners of the view's layer.
- creating a custom CircleView that sets `backgroundColor` to `[UIColor clearColor]` and manually drawing the circle on in `drawRect`.

In each case, when the view flips to the new view, it's a rectangular portion of the screen that flips, not just the circle. I'd like the flip to just be the circle, but I'm not sure where to go next.

Here's the method I'm using to flip the view currently:

```
-(void)changeSpotToView:(SpotView *)toView {
    [UIView transitionFromView:self.activeView
                        toView:toView
                      duration:1.0
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop
                    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                        self.activeView = toView;
                    }];

}
```

The container the `SpotView`s are in is also a `SpotView`, so it should be just a circle as well.

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Post the code that animates the flipping.

Comment: Done, though I doubt it'll provide much help specifically with this. The problem seems to be that UIKit sees the whole frame as the view, and not just the visible portion, so it's a rectangular flip, not a circular flip.

Comment: @CodaFi Views can have transparent parts.  It is reasonable to expect those parts to remain transparent during animations.

Comment: Perhaps he has an incorrect opaque setting then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `transitionFromView:toView:…` animates the superview of the `fromView`.

I reproduced the problem:

[image]

I was able to fix it in my test case simply by embedding my `fromView` and `toView` in a container view with a clear background.  Here's my working version:

[image: working flip]

My nib looks like this:

[image: nib]

I have bounds rectangles enabled (Editor > Canvas > Show Bounds Rectangles), so you can see the outline of the container view, which is bigger than its subviews.

I have a red view and a blue view as subviews of the container view.  The blue view is behind the red view and has the same frame.  I apply circular masks to them in code.

Here's my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.blueView.hidden = YES;
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self addCircleMaskToView:self.blueView];
    [self addCircleMaskToView:self.redView];
}

- (void)addCircleMaskToView:(UIView *)view {
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.frame = view.bounds;
    maskLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:view.bounds].CGPath;
    maskLayer.fillColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    view.layer.mask = maskLayer;
}

- (IBAction)buttonWasTapped:(id)sender {
    [UIView transitionFromView:self.redView toView:self.blueView
        duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop
        | UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews
        completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Rob, this looks great! I'll give it a shot today.

Comment: Can you please tell me how you created those gifs out of the iOS simulator?

Comment: I used Snapz Pro X to record the screen to a movie file.  Then I imported the movie frames as layers in Photoshop, trimmed off the unneeded frames, and saved it using Save For Web.